# Determining the bounds of integration after switching to polar coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, substitution

the integral I am solving is:
$$I=\iint_Sxy\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy$$
where $S$ is a rectangle $0\le x\le1, 0\le y\le1$
after $$x=\rho\cos{\varphi},y=\rho\sin{\varphi}$$
$$dy\,dx=\rho \,d\rho \,d\varphi$$
Where i struggle is finding the bounds for integration after the switch. Drawing the area, i see, for $\varphi\in (0,\pi/4)$ $r$ goes from $0$ to $1/\cos{\varphi}$ and for $\varphi\in(\pi/4,\pi/2)$ $r$ goes from $0$ to $1/\sin{\varphi}$. If i divided the integral into two (four), i obtain:
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{2} \sin{2\varphi} \int_0^{1/\cos{\varphi}} \rho^3\sqrt{1+\rho^2} \, d\rho +\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{2} \sin{2\varphi} \int_0^{1/\sin{\varphi}} \rho^3\sqrt{1+\rho^2} \, d\rho$$
Is this approach correct or I am doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to use polar coordinates at all? Are you open to not?

Comment: Of course i would be open for that, but still would like to know if my approach was correct.

Comment: I don't have the time at the moment to check your work, but would be happy to show you how to do this with just cartesian if you would like. In general integrating in polar over a rectangle is going to get messy

Comment: Yeah, i see. :D Anyways, I am definitely interested in your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the computation since I did not check, however integrating over a rectangle using polar coordinates is often a bad idea (even if you see a $x^2+y^2$ in the integrand!).

This integral in particular is not too bad in cartesian,
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 xy\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}\;\mathrm dy \mathrm dx\\
\stackrel{u=1+x^2+y^2\implies \mathrm du=2y\mathrm dy}{=}
\frac12\int_0^1x\int_1^{2+x^2} \sqrt{u}\mathrm \;du \mathrm dx\\
=\frac13\int_0^1x\left((2+x^2)^{3/2}-1 \right)\mathrm dx\\
=\frac13\int_0^1x(2+x^2)^{3/2}\;\mathrm dx-\frac{1}{3} \int_0^1x\;\mathrm dx 
$$
both of which are easy to evaluate.

Comment: I should really stop thinking in polars, i see the simplicity now. Thank you

Comment: @MichalDvořák: Keep in mind that the coordinate choice (cartesian or polar) is informed by the shape of the domain as well as the expression in the integrand.  I can see how you went to polar seeing the $x^2 + y^2$ term, but the domain is a square.  In English we have this phrase “putting a square peg into a round hole” for doing something that's difficult because of incompatible design.  That's literally the case here.

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be computed by exploiting symmetry, rather than *putting a square peg into a round hole* (I loved Matthew Leingang's comments above).
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \iint_{(0,1)^2}xy\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}\,dx \,dy &=& 2 \iint_{0\leq y\leq x\leq 1}xy\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy\\&=&2\iint_{(0,1)^2} x^3 z\sqrt{1+x^2+x^2 z^2}\,dz\,dx\\&=&\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{1}x\left((2x^2+1)^{3/2}-(x^2+1)^{3/2}\right)\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{15}\left[(2x^2+1)^{5/2}-2(x^2+1)^{5/2}\right]_{0}^{1}\\[0.2cm]&=&\color{blue}{\frac{9\sqrt{3}-8\sqrt{2}+1}{15}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$